# how many conditions can a while loop check in one statement

Tags: php, while-loop, conditional-statements

Simple question, how many conditions can one WHILE statement check?
I have already guessed that one factor is processor and memory, but what I am wondering if there is a specified limit or restriction on the number of conditions that can be checked.

```
    WHILE(something1 && something2 && something3 && ...)
        {
       some code1;
        some code2;
         some code3;
          ...
        }// if this helps visualize the question
```

I am not the best at asking questions, so hope this is understandable.
thanks

For the record: The answer below returns true, but while loop can give some unexpected results with many conditions and many codes to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is strange, but there is no limitation on conditions just as there is no definitive limit on statements in a source file.

For PHP, the conditions will be evaluated left to right until a single boolean is formed and accepted by the while().

Comment: Thank you for an actual answer. I assumed this was the case but could not find a verifying reference.